# How to set Bootstrap container width spanning full screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

my webpage has the html code as below and I am having a container in the last section with a jumbotron inside. I wish to have this container displayed filling the entiree screen and curently there is a margin around it. How can I eliminate the margin for this last container with id footerContainer?

```
{% extends 'indexBase.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block coverContent %}
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id = "header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1 class="display-4">Hidden Dimsum</h1>
      <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor cumque perferendis consequatur minima quaerat placeat, tempora rerum iusto similique quia illum necessitatibus praesentium voluptate voluptatem possimus esse iure quidem dignissimos!</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block mainNavContent %}
<div class="container-fluid">
        
    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
            <a href='#'>
                <img class="card-img-top" src={% static 'media/HiddenDimsumNytorvFacade.jpg' %} alt="Hidden Dimsum Nytorv image">
            </a>
        <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Hidden Dimsum Nytorv </h5>
            <p class="card-text">Our main dimsum house located at heart of Copenhagen. This is the place where
                dimsum started.
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Book table</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="card-img-top" src={% static 'media/HiddenDimsumByNight.jpg' %} alt="Hidden Dimsum By Night">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Hidden Dimsum by Night</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Late night dimsum and Hongkong street food with Asian beers. A night has different shades!</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Opening Hours</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
        
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="card-img-top" src={% static 'media/HiddenDimsum2900Facade.jpg' %} alt="Hidden Dimsum Strandvejen 163, 2900 Hellerup">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Hidden Dimsum 2900</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Dimsum takeaway. Order your dimsum dinner and pick it up at Hidden Dimsum 2900, Strandvejen 163, 2900 Hellerup.</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Order takeaway online></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Order takeaway over phone</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Opening hours</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="card-img-top" src={% static 'media/DimsumBox.jpg' %} alt="Dimsum Box">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Dimsum Box</h5>
            <p class="card-text">A box of dimsum delivered to your front door with instructions on how to warm up. Dimsum at your convenience!</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Order</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block landingPageFooter %}
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="footerJumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="footerContainer">
      <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
      <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and the css

```
#header {
    text-align: center; 
    background: url("media/cover.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}

body {
    background-color: #d48498;
}

.p-2 {
    font-size : 50px;
    font-weight : bold;
}

a > img {width : 500px;}

#footerJumbotron {
    margin-top : 16px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

#footerContainer {
    margin: 0px;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

This is how it renders out
[image]

I need the #footerContainer to be rendered out in full screen width and I have tried to set margin to 0px in my css. Still a margin exists in my footer container. Also it doesn't seem that setting max-width to 100% helps in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need more CSS, the `jumbotron-fluid` already is full screen width.

The issue is that the preceding `container-fluid` is missing it's last closing `</div>` before the `#footerJumbotron` starts. Make sure the HTML is properly structured, and it works as expected...

https://codeply.com/p/vAILLQXEHM

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
            <a href='#'>
            </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Hidden Dimsum Nytorv </h5>
                <p class="card-text">Our main dimsum house located at heart of Copenhagen. This is the place where dimsum started. <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Book table</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <a href="#">
            </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Hidden Dimsum by Night</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Late night dimsum and Hongkong street food with Asian beers. A night has different shades!</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Opening Hours</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <a href="#">
            </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Hidden Dimsum 2900</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Dimsum takeaway. Order your dimsum dinner and pick it up at Hidden Dimsum 2900, Strandvejen 163, 2900 Hellerup.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Order takeaway online></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Order takeaway over phone</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Opening hours</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <a href="#">
            </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Dimsum Box</h5>
                <p class="card-text">A box of dimsum delivered to your front door with instructions on how to warm up. Dimsum at your convenience!</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Order</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="footerJumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="footerContainer">
        <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
        <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for spotting this. I am using visual studio code for writing the html code. However the editor doesn't offer an easy way to spot such issues. I am right now manually counting the number of <div>s in a section.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way you do this

1. Add **Class = container-fluid** div after the **Id = footerContainer** div and gave background to **Id = footerContainer** div.
2. With css add padding left and right 0px to **Id = footerContainer** div ID

   #footerContainer  {
   padding-left: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
   }

Comment: Thanks for your comments. That doesn't help it is the grey jumbotron box itself I want to stretch out so it fills the entire screen. Not the text content inside the jumbotron.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, just add these rules to your css:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0!important;
    padding-left: 0!important;
}

.card-deck {
    margin-right: 0!important;
    margin-left: 0!important;
}
```

...also, add `padding-left: 15px` and `padding-right: 15px` to `#footerJumbotron`.

```css
#header {
    text-align: center; 
    background: url("media/cover.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}

body {
    background-color: #d48498;
}

.p-2 {
    font-size : 50px;
    font-weight : bold;
}

a > img {width : 500px;}

#footerJumbotron {
    margin-top : 16px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    
    padding-left: 15px; /*add this it*/
    padding-right: 15px; /*add this it*/
}

#footerContainer {
    margin: 0px;
    max-width:100%;
}

/*add this it*/

.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0!important;
    padding-left: 0!important;
}

.card-deck {
    margin-right: 0!important;
    margin-left: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id = "header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1 class="display-4">Hidden Dimsum</h1>
      <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor cumque perferendis consequatur minima quaerat placeat, tempora rerum iusto similique quia illum necessitatibus praesentium voluptate voluptatem possimus esse iure quidem dignissimos!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
        
    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
            <a href='#'>
                <img class="card-img-top" src={% static 'media/HiddenDimsumNytorvFacade.jpg' %} alt="Hidden Dimsum Nytorv image">
            </a>
        <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Hidden Dimsum Nytorv </h5>
            <p class="card-text">Our main dimsum house located at heart of Copenhagen. This is the place where
                dimsum started.
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Book table</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="card-img-top" src={% static 'media/HiddenDimsumByNight.jpg' %} alt="Hidden Dimsum By Night">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Hidden Dimsum by Night</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Late night dimsum and Hongkong street food with Asian beers. A night has different shades!</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Opening Hours</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
        
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="card-img-top" src={% static 'media/HiddenDimsum2900Facade.jpg' %} alt="Hidden Dimsum Strandvejen 163, 2900 Hellerup">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Hidden Dimsum 2900</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Dimsum takeaway. Order your dimsum dinner and pick it up at Hidden Dimsum 2900, Strandvejen 163, 2900 Hellerup.</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Order takeaway online></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Order takeaway over phone</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Opening hours</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="card-img-top" src={% static 'media/DimsumBox.jpg' %} alt="Dimsum Box">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Dimsum Box</h5>
            <p class="card-text">A box of dimsum delivered to your front door with instructions on how to warm up. Dimsum at your convenience!</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Order</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="footerJumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="footerContainer">
      <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
      <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```